# Как настроить NUnit тесты на TeamCity?

Tags: teamcity, nunit

Имеется TeamCity с тремя агентами и порядка 20 билд конфигурациями, которые билдят разные ветки c# проекта.

Заметил, что когда запускается сразу несколько билдов, то некоторые юнит тесты падают. И ошибка не пропадает до тех пор пока я не удалю `.emdx` файл бд с агента. Для тестирования используется `NUnit`, в каждом проекте с тестами есть App.config где забит путь до базы на которой тесты прогоняются...И эта база одна. А, вот в каждой ветке проекта есть изменения базы.

Так же в проекте бд в visual studia вижу что стоит галочка `пересоздавать базу данных`. Т.е. как я понимаю при каждом билде бд на которой прогоняются тесты пересоздастся.

И я хочу понять почему так происходит. Как мне настроить прогон юнит тестов при запуске множества билдов одновременно?

На видосах с конференций, вижу, что у людей тысячи билд конфигураций и сотни агентов, значит как-то крутят юнит тесты.

Понимаю, что сумбурно описал проблему, но никогда этим не занимался, и не знаю куда начать смотреть.